# How would I sort through lists of frequently used words to find efficient combinations using the most unique words as possible?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, set-cover

I have lists of the most frequently used words, derived from Google's publicly available ngram data.

I have:

6800 frequent 2grams
4800 frequent 3grams
2500 frequent 4grams
1100 frequent 5grams

an example 2 ngram would be something like:

"the dog" 
"a book" 
"three chairs" 
etc.

an example 5 ngram would be something like:
"once upon a time there"
"upon a time there was"
"it was a dark and"
etc.

I also have a list of 2,000 frequent words.

1) I want to find out which combination of the fewest number of ngrams from my various lists contains the most number of words from the frequent word list.

For example, if I found 200 2grams, 40 3 grams, 50 4 grams, and 20 5 grams that used 1800 of the frequent words, that would be a success. I made those ratios up, but I would like to find less than 500 combinations that use the majority of the words.

2) I would also like to find the smallest number of combinations of the various ngrams that contains the highest total amount of words from the lists.

For example, if I could find 500 ngrams that use over 2000 different words, that would be great.

The problem I am having is that I have no idea how I would go about doing this. I think hadoop and mapreduce are in the right direction... but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Jeremy, can you please let us know what kind of background you have in CS?

Comment: @AlptiginJalayr I am confident in PHP, JavaScript, and MySQL... but have never ventured into any sort of machine learning like this before. This is probably a bit out of my league, but I was hoping to at least try to understand the technology that would be involved in a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have on the order of 15k ngrams.  This is an extremely small data set.  It will likely fit into 1 MB of memory, probably less than 1/5000 of the total memory on your machine.  You don't need hadoop to solve such a problem.  Further, it's not really a machine learning problem at all, it's just an optimization problem.

You could think of your n-grams as (small) sets of words, and your frequent word list as a larger set.  For your first problem, you want to pick the fewest number of n-grams such that you can cover (or come as close to covering as possible) the frequent word list with those n-grams.  This is exactly a [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).  You probably won't get an exact solution, but there are simple heuristics that do well.

I am not totally clear on how your first problem differs from your second problem, however.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I was over thinking it. Time to email my friend over at Cambridge - now that I know what I am asking! I really appreciate your response. Cheers.